# What are the guidelines for showing many columns in an ipad app?

Tags: tables, ios, info-visualisation, human-interface-guideline

I'm creating an app for an ipad where it should show a table with someinformation, more than 7 columns. I looked in to Human Interface Guidelines for tables but there is only information for tables with one column and navigation. What are the guidelines for tables with more than one column? Am I supposed to show the information in another way and not a table with multiple columns? I'm thinking in something like https://www.ag-grid.com/ Are this kind of grids used in iOS Apps? The app will only be used on ipads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16715/design-patterns-or-strategies-for-complex-or-large-table-data-in-mobile-phones

Comment: That does not solve it since it´s for mobiles, they are talkin about smaller screens. What I am looking for ipad followind the HIG from apple.